# select system occaionally not failing with EINTR

Tags: linux

Using `timer_create`, we deliver a real time signal to a thread which waits on `select` function.

This signal is caught and handled in the thread. Based on fact the select will be interrupted when a signal is caught, I have some logic implemented if `select` fails with error number `EINTR`.

This works fine most of the time, but occasionally I notice that `select` is not getting interrupted (or some how the code within `EINTR` case not getting executed).

What are possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 2):

It can be that when the timer expiry signal is delivered you are not waiting in `select`, hence it does not return `EINTR`.

If you want to receive `EINTR` only when the thread is blocked in `select`, you may block that signal in the thread using [`pthread_sigmask`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) and use [`pselect`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pselect.html) or [`epoll_pwait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) that would unblock that signal while waiting only. This way the rest of your code does not need to be concerned with handling `EINTR`.

If you have more than one thread in the process make sure you block that signal in all other threads, so that only one thread gets delivered that signal. See [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) for more details.

A more elegant option (IMO) is to avoid using `timer_create` and rather pass the delay to the next timer expiry as `select` time-out argument (this is what [libevent](http://libevent.org/) does). But that requires you to maintain your own min-heap of timers.

Comment: To elaborate further, if the logic fails , we kill that process with sigabrt and get the core. From the core, it appears that the thread is blocked on select call. One more thing, we don't fail this logic immediately, we wait for nearly 1 min before killing the process.

Comment: @user3816365 If you have more than one thread in the process make sure you block that signal in all other threads, so that only one thread gets delivered that signal. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Comment: This signal is blocked by all the other threads in the process.